# type 'any' has no subscript members error with map

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

Ive tried for hours with every possible combination and can't get this to work.

my function:

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    let todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)

    return items.map({TodoItem(
        deadline: $0["deadline"] as! Date,
        title: $0["title"] as! String, 
        UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!,
        description: $0["description"] as! String,
        imageSavePath: ($0["imageSavePath"] as! String),
        isItComplete: $0["isItComplete"] as! Bool
    )}).sorted(by: {(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .orderedAscending)
    })
}
```

Gives me the error 'type 'Any' has no subscript members.
I have researched and tried to alter:

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem]
```

to

```
func allItems() -> [Any:[TodoItem]]
```

However this raises the error that 'Type Any does not conform to Hashable protocol'. Is this the right lines to go down?

Please help.....before my macbook goes out the window!

Comment: Isn't there a design mistake? A dictionary a an object with key /  value pairs. Your mapping works only if each **value** is itself a dictionary which I doubt.

Comment: What are you actually trying to return, an Array, or a dictionary?

Comment: This worked perfectly prior to swift 3.0 so I don't think this is a design mistake. The aim is to return an array of 'ToDoItems' which are sorted by DueDate.

Comment: Then you must tell the compiler – which is confused as I am at the moment – what `values` really contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care of the types of the variables.

`dictionary(forKey:)` returns `[String: Any]`, so `todoDictionary` is a `[String: Any]`.

(In older Swift, Value type of generic dictionary was imported as `AnyObject`, but now it's `Any`.)

You are retrieving only values and making it to an Array, so `items` is an `Array<Any>`.

Then you are applying `map` to `items`, so `$0` in it is an `Any`.

Thus, you cannot apply any methods including subscript to `Any`.

---

If you need to apply `$0["deadline"]` or something and the values may differ, the type of `$0` needs to be a Dictionary with its Key type `String` and its Value type mixed, which is represented by `Any` in Swift 3.

The type `$0` needs to be `[String: Any]`, so the type of `items` needs to be `Array<[String: Any]>` (aka `[[String: Any]]`).

Which means the Value type of `todoDictionary` needs to be `[String: Any]`, its Key type is already constrained to `String`, so the type of `todoDictionary` needs to be `[String: [String: Any]]`.

---

Conclusion, change the first line of your `allItems()` to this:

```
let todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) as? [String: [String: Any]] ?? [:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're taking only the `values` out of the dictionary. You're then trying to subscript these `Any` instances with Strings, which won't work because the compiler has no idea if those `Any` instances are guaranteed to be `Dictionaries` or anything else that can be subscripted by a `String`.

Your question is quite lacking and doesn't convert what you're actually trying to achieve. I suspect you're trying to map a `[String: [String: Any]]` to a `[String: TodoItem]`, here are your issues:

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    let todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:] //inferred type: [String: Any]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values) //inferred type [Any]

    return items.map({TodoItem(
        deadline: $0["deadline"] as! Date, //[Any] can only be subscripted by indices, not by string.
        title: $0["title"] as! String, 
        UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!,
        description: $0["description"] as! String,
        imageSavePath: ($0["imageSavePath"] as! String),
        isItComplete: $0["isItComplete"] as! Bool
    )}).sorted(by: {(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .orderedAscending)
    })
}
```